# How to pass parameter values directly into TestNG, JUnit or other framework method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, testng

Basically I'm trying to accomplish what in C#'s NUnit is very simple, but using a Java test framework.

What I want to accomplish in Java would look like this in C#'s Nunit:

```
[Test]
[TestCase(ProcessTypes.A, "a", false, true, false), Category("Smoke")]
[TestCase(ProcessTypes.A, "A", false, false, true), Category("Functional")]
[TestCase(ProcessTypes.A, "*", false, false, false), Category("Functional")]
public void ProcessIsResponding(ProcessTypes ProcessType, string password, bool lengthPass, bool lowercasePass, bool uppercasePass) {
    ...
    // perform test using parameters
    ...
}
```

In this case, I write a test method and use annotations to define the parameter values, and the values only need to match the test method arguments. Then it is invoked for each TestCase annotation, each time with a different set of parameter values. That is so much more practical than having to annotate the test with parameter names and put value in an external XML file... `DataProvider`s then are extremely cumbersome when you have a large number of tests.

It seems like TestNG was the most promising framework out there, but it has the whole "parameter values in an xml file" architecture, which is awful.

I'm willing to put in the effort to witch frameworks if anyone else would have this kind of structure.

Can this be accomplished with any other test framework for Java out there?

Answer (score 1):

All of the test frameworks you mentioned allow for loading of properties on startup, which can be used instead of parameters. The properties can be read from the command line, from environment vars, from properties files, etc.

TestNG also allows for parameters, such as

import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

```
public class ParameterizedTest1 {
    @Test
    @Parameters("myName")
    public void parameterTest(String myName) {
        System.out.println("Parameterized value is : " + myName);
    }
}
```

take a look: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_parameterized_test.htm

Comment: Oh, yeah, my point is that I'd like the parameter *values* to be in the annotations, not in a separate file like TestNG apparently requires. In the example you posted, I'd have to put the parameter values in testng.xml for example, which is a very cumbersome compared to the approach taken by NUnit. I'm curious on whether any  of these frameworks can work in a similar way, with parameter values in the test annotation, not in an external place.

Comment: I understand now. You can use parameters in the annotation if you use a DataProvider. http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders, but the most common usage is via properties files because then we can have an environment-driven tests. They are not really annotations, but you can also use the @optional. For example: `public void testNonExistentParameter(@Optional("mysql") String db) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

in java annotations you can use only simple types. in junit you can do parameterized testing with [zohhak](https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak). it let's you write

```
@TestWith({
    "clerk,      45'000 USD, GOLD",
    "supervisor, 60'000 GBP, PLATINUM"
})
public void canAcceptDebit(Employee employee, Money money, ClientType clientType) {
    assertTrue(   employee.canAcceptDebit(money, clientType)   );
}
```

i'm not aware if there is something similar in testNG but it's rather easy to implement using custom dataprovider that scans annotations of a current test method

you can also check [spock](https://code.google.com/p/spock/). it let's you write tests in groovy (and run them as junit) therefore you have more powerful syntax